# How to open new terminal window python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal, subprocess

I have to create some terminal windows ( one for each subprocess) and to see them.
I’m having troubles also due to the fact that the subprocess are not called as different script but they are functions of the main script

Comment: plz specify your operating system

Comment: It is windows, but I’d like to know also in Linux if it is different